# Brownian motion: find the backward conditional probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion.

I want to compute $P[W_1+W_2>3|W_3=4]$.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You should include context as to what you've tried and where you're stuck. From what I can glean from your title the fact that it conditions on future data might be problematic for you, but a little use of Bayes can express things in terms of more intuitive conditioning on past data.

Comment: It seems hard to deal with the zero-probability condition if we apply Bayes theorem. Now I think it can be done by finding out the conditional distribution directly.

Comment: Yep definitely can, after all we always know the joint distribution of $W_t$ for any set of times. Apologies for the marginal advice. (You can handle the zero probability event in the usual way... as a density. But if I were to do it, I would choose a way closer to what you ended up doing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U=W_1+W_2,V=W_3$, then $(U,V)^{'}$ obeys bivariate normal distribution with mean $(0,0)^{'}$ and

$Var[U]=Var[W_1]+Var[W_2]+2Cov[W_1,W_2]=5$

$Var[V]=3$

$Cov[U,V]=Cov[W_1,W_3]+Cov[W_2,W_3]=3$

Thus, we obtain the conditional distribution $U|V=4$~$N(4,2)$.

$P[U>3|V=4]=\Phi(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$